# What is the effect of customizing your weapon in Warface?

Tags: warface

In Warface it's possible to customize your weapon in-game by pressing `C`. You can then choose to add a silencer, scope, etc.

I know the silencer reduces the sound of your shots, and the scope gives you a scope when right-clicking. Beside these, is there also an effect on any of the other properties of the weapon?  Damage, recoil, etc.?

Comment: There's a demo out or am I missing something?

Comment: @Warface The game is currently live in Russia (this is the one I play) and has an open beta in China. I understand this lowers the amount of people that can answer this question but if people are voting to close it would be nice if they *at least* left a comment why.

Comment: This question seems fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

There are several effects on weapons achieved with customization.
Most commons:

- Silencer: Eliminates sound, Improves Accuracy, Decrease damage, Increases penetration.
- Bipod: Impoves Accuracy, Reduces Recoil, Reduces Sway.
- Bayonet: Increase melee attack damage.
- Grip: Improves Accuracy, Reduces Recoil.
- See more at http://warface.wikia.com/wiki/Equipment

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that silencer reduces recoil & damage, but that's speculative; tt feels like I need one extra bullet to kill someone when I'm using a silencer.

Comment: Welcome to Arquade. When you answer questions, then please don't post speculations. Only post what you have verified yourself or what you know from a trustworthy source (which you should link to).

Answer (score -1):

The silencer does reduce damage but some increase accuracy.

Comment: Please use [this link](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/189028/edit) to edit your answer and only post a second answer if it is vastly different from your previous one. from the 2 answer i see you have posted they can be put into the same answer